# C# notation understanding Select(int.Parse)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, notation

I found a little script that I understand fully. I've got a string with "*1 -2 5 40*" for example. It reads the input string, splits it into a temporary array. Then this array is parsed and each element is transformed into an integer. The whole thing is order to give the nearest integer to zero.

But what I don't understand is the notation **Select(int.Parse)**. There is no lambda expression here and the method int.Parse isn't called with brackets. Same with the **OrderBy(Math.Abs)**

Thank you in advance =)

```
var temps = Console.ReadLine().Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);  

var result = temps.Select(int.Parse)
.OrderBy(Math.Abs)
.ThenByDescending(x => x)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 12):

`int.Parse` is a *method group* - what you're seeing is a method group conversion to a delegate. To see it without LINQ:

```
Func<string, int> parser = int.Parse;
int x = parser("10"); // x=10
```

It's mostly equivalent to:

```
Func<string, int> parser = text => int.Parse(text);
```

... although there are plenty of differences if you want to go into the details :)

Answer (score 7):

`Select(int.Parse)` is nearly equivalent to `Select(x => int.Parse(x))`.

The `Select` demands an `Func<T, R>`, which in this case is also the signature of `int.Parse` (it has a single parameter with a return value). It convers the method group to the matching delegate.

In this case `Func<T, R>` will map to `Func<string, int>`, so it matches the `int Parse(string)` signature.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for `.Select()` is `Func<T1, T2>()` where `T1` is the input parameter (the individual values of `temps`), and `T2` is the return type.

Typically, this is written as a lambda function: `x => return x + 1`, etc. However, any method that fits the generic definitions can be used without having to be written as a lambda since the method name is the same as assigning the lambda to a variable.

So `Func<string, int> parseInt = s => Convert.ToInt32(s);` is syntactically equivalent to calling the method `int.Parse(s)`.

The language creates the shortcut of automatically passing the Func parameter to the inside method to create more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse is a method with signature string -> int (or actually, a method group, with different signatures. But the compiler can infer you need this one, because it is the only one that fits.

You could use this method as a parameter wherever you would supply a delegate parameter with the same signature.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can use it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Select LINQ IEnumerable<> extension method signature looks like that:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector
)
```

Look at the `selector` argument. In your case you pass to Select .Net standard function `int.Parse` which has signature:

```
public static int Parse(
    string s
)
```

.Net compiler can convert delegates to Func<...> or Action<...>. In case of int.Parse it can be converted to Func and therefore can be passed as argument to Select method.

Exactly the same with OrderBy. Look at its signature too.